# timer based on count in python

Tags: python

I am trying to pass my query value to an external API, but since the API has a throttling issue I can make only 500 calls per 5 mins and need to give 10 mins of cooling time. so what I am trying, I added a count increment method and if the count passes more than 400 then sleep for 2 mins, I know the mistake is in my code, but I don't know how to write a function to it.

```py
for info in contact:
    id = info[0]
    name = info[1]

    print(id)
    count += 1
    print(count)

    if count > 400:
        print('11111111')
        time.sleep(120)
        print ("count crossed 400....")
        print ("sleep for 2 minutes")
    else:
        logging.info(count)
        print(name) 
        try:
            ...
```

so this will check the count and if the count is more than 400 it will sleep 2 minutes for every other call till the completion.
I am trying to make it in such a way that for every 400 calls sleep for 2 mins how to write that in python. kindly guide

Comment: i think **count** and its **time sleep** should be the argument of a function which defines max api call https://realpython.com/python-sleep/

Comment: You do not reset `count`, so you will sleep 120 seconds for EACH call after the 400th. Is this what you want, or do you want to sleep on the 400th, the 800th, the 1200th, etc. only?

Comment: i am a newbee in python can i write it for me. It whould sleep for 400,800  and so on but the overall count will be around 4.5 million

Comment: Reset the count to 0 when if conditions becomes true or else it will always go to sleep because of count>400.

Comment: or you can just update it to count%400==0

Answer (score 2):

```py
for info in contact:
        id = info[0]
        name = info[1] 
        print(id)
        count += 1
        print(count)
        if count > 400:
            print('11111111')
            time.sleep(120)
            count = 0
            print ("count crossed 400....")
            print ("sleep for 2 minutes")
        else:
            logging.info(count)
            print(name)
```

add the line : `count = 0`, it reset the variable `count` to 0 `if count > 400`

Comment: this works fine for my requirement!!

Comment: I would also suggest to try @Carrot solution: if count%400 == 0, more elegant and cleaner.

Comment: You might also use `for i, info in enumerate(contact):` and then `% i`